# How to access the elements in a list of dict keys and values for writing to csv rows in Python

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary, export-to-csv

I have my code working for writing a single json dictionary keys and values to a csv file iterating over a flat dict, like so.

Json Input:

```
{"id": 1702, "subnet": "10.111.0.0", "mask": "21", "sectionId": 3, "description": "POD", "linked_subnet": null, "firewallAddressObject": null, "vrfId": null, "masterSubnetId": 1158, "allowRequests": 0, "vlanId": null, "showName": 0, "device": null, "permissions": "{\"4\":\"3\"}", "pingSubnet": 0, "discoverSubnet": 0, "resolveDNS": 0, "DNSrecursive": 0, "DNSrecords": 0, "nameserverId": 0, "scanAgent": 0, "customer_id": null, "isFolder": 0, "isFull": 0, "isPool": 0, "tag": 2, "threshold": 0, "location": null, "editDate": null, "lastScan": null, "lastDiscovery": null, "calculation": {"Type": "IPv4", "IP address": "/", "Network": "10.111.0.0", "Broadcast": "10.111.7.255", "Subnet bitmask": "21", "Subnet netmask": "255.255.248.0", "Subnet wildcard": "0.0.7.255", "Min host IP": "10.111.0.1", "Max host IP": "10.111.7.254", "Number of hosts": "2046", "Subnet Class": "private A"}}
```

My code for this is:

```
rawdata = json.loads(res.content)
json_data_dict = json.dumps(rawdata)
print(f"\nPRINTING JSON DICT DATA\n {json_data_dict}")

json_parse = json.loads(json_data_dict, object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict)

with open('ipamsubnet.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    writer.writerow(json_parse["data"].keys())  # header row
    writer.writerow(json_parse["data"].values())
```

And the csv file row looks correct for this single dictionary data output from the json data structure above.

What I am trying to do is now access nested dict elements that are in a list of dicts because there are subnets under the aforementioned master subnet dictionary that need to be accounted for in the csv but the json data structure returned from the API call is no longer a dictionary but rather a list of dicts.

Here is an excerpt of the nested data structure:

List of dicts, Input 2:

```
"data": [{"id": 1713, "subnet": "10.111.0.0", "mask": "27", "sectionId": 3, "description": "POD_Site", "linked_subnet": null, "firewallAddressObject": null, "vrfId": null, "masterSubnetId": 1702, "allowRequests": 0, "vlanId": null, "showName": 0, "device": null, "permissions": "{\"4\":\"3\"}", "pingSubnet": 0, "discoverSubnet": 0, "resolveDNS": 0, "DNSrecursive": 0, "DNSrecords": 0, "nameserverId": 0, "scanAgent": 0, "customer_id": null, "isFolder": 0, "isFull": 0, "isPool": 0, "tag": 2, "threshold": 0, "location": null, "editDate": null, "lastScan": null, "lastDiscovery": null}, {"id": 1714, "subnet": "10.111.0.32", "mask": "27", "sectionId": 3, "description": "POD_Site", "linked_subnet": null, "firewallAddressObject": null, "vrfId": null, "masterSubnetId": 1702, "allowRequests": 0, "vlanId": null, "showName": 0, "device": null, "permissions": "{\"4\":\"3\"}", "pingSubnet": 0, "discoverSubnet": 0, "resolveDNS": 0, "DNSrecursive": 0, "DNSrecords": 0, "nameserverId": 0, "scanAgent": 0, "customer_id": null, "isFolder": 0, "isFull": 0, "isPool": 0, "tag": 2, "threshold": 0, "location": null, "editDate": null, "lastScan": null, "lastDiscovery": null}, {"id": 1715, "subnet": "10.111.0.64", "mask": "27", "sectionId": 3, "description": "POD_Site", "linked_subnet": null, "firewallAddressObject": null, "vrfId": null, "masterSubnetId": 1702, "allowRequests": 0, "vlanId": null, "showName": 0, "device": null, "permissions": "{\"4\":\"3\"}", "pingSubnet": 0, "discoverSubnet": 0, "resolveDNS": 0, "DNSrecursive": 0, "DNSrecords": 0, "nameserverId": 0, "scanAgent": 0, "customer_id": null, "isFolder": 0, "isFull": 0, "isPool": 0, "tag": 2, "threshold": 0, "location": null, "editDate": null, "lastScan": null, "lastDiscovery": null}]
```

Is `data` now a dict of list of dicts where `data` is the key and the value is a list of dicts, or just a list of dicts?

Objective is to have the csv contain the number of rows according to each `id` key which signifies a the start of another dictionary, and each dictionary is a list index element, at least that is how I understand it.

Is something like this headed in the right direction:

```
'Key': list(data)[0]
'Value': list(data.values()[0]
```

Any guidance is much appreciated.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Instead of a screenshot of Excel, please post the actual CSV content. Also, please post a [example]. It would be much clearer to post a complete data structure with 2 keys rather than an incomplete data structure with 31 keys. Finally, it would be much safer to use [`csv.DictWriter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter) than to try to homebrew it with `csv.writer` and `.values()`: your approach will fall apart if there is any difference in the dict structure, even insertion order.

Comment: I will edit my post accordingly. Thanks!

Comment: @humbleStrength, +you don't seem to be entirely confident/sure about what you're trying to achieve. Can you please modify your post and show a clear input (*json?*) and the matching expected output (*.csv*?).

Comment: @Amadan how do I post the actual csv content? I copied the content, but it prompts it as an image.

Comment: In Python, the equivalent of null is None.

Comment: @Timeless I edited my json info in the post for more clarity/correctness. However, I am unable to post the csv output unless it is an image/screenshot which is not acceptable according to Amadan.

Comment: Your two inputs are not valid JSON (*can you parse them? No*). Also, we still don't understand where/what are your input(s) (type, format, source,.. ) and what is your exact expected output (type, format, ...) that matches that or those inputs. PS: It's ok to show a screenshot of your desired csv if this one can't fit the post.

Comment: CSV is text. Excel can read CSV files, and it may be that on your system it is the default opener for a `.csv` extension, but it is not the primary representation of CSV. E.g. a CSV file might look like this: first row: `id,subnet,mask`, second row: `1713,10.111.0.0,27`, third row: `1714,10.111.0.32,27`. (Obviously I can't format it well in a comment.) It is not an image, it is text. Also, your dict has a `calculation` field which is itself a dict; CSV does not handle nested structures. This is why we want to see a [example], both for input and output, that would show us your expectations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/) :

```
import pandas as pd

json_parse = {"data" : [
    {'id': 1713, 'subnet': '10.111.0.0', 'mask': '27'},
    {'id': 1714, 'subnet': '10.111.0.32', 'mask': '27'},
    {'id': 1715, 'subnet': '10.111.0.64', 'mask': '27'}
]}

# create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(json_parse["data"])

# save csv file
df.to_csv('ipamsubnet.csv', index=False)
```